# Angular component binding but no data transfer

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have two components in my page. Component A called **Dashboard** and contains a list of elements via ng-repeat, let's call it **systems**. Each system will be displayed via a component B, a component especially for this system element it's called **SystemView**. Each system view has a list of log entries and what i now want, is to display a badge with the amount of unread log entries.
If i open a system entry i'm able to set a log entry to read, wo the number of unread log entries should change.
For your understanding: `system.logEntries` is a list of log entries.

**HTML**

```
<some-accordion-control>
  <div ng-repeat="system in systems">
    <h3>{{system.name}} <span class="badge">{{system.unreadLogEntries}} of {{system.logEntries.length}}</span>
    <system-view system="system"></system-view>
  </div>
</some-accordion-control>
```

**JS SystemView Controller**

```
module.exports = {
  template: 'some.html',
  controller: SystemView,
  bindings: {
    system: '<'
  }
};

function SystemView() {
    // ... some code
}

SystemView.prototype = {
  setRead: function () {
    // this is an example that i change the value of unreadLogEntries
    // this did not work in the dashboard component
    system.unreadLogEntries--;
    // i tried this and it worked in the dashboard component
    system.logEntries.push({
      message: "Hello World!"
    });
  }
};
```

My problem here is, that the list of log entries could change and gets the new information about it's values. But the simple integer field `unreadLogEntries` not.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did the following to hit this:

I removed the unreadLogEntries field and added a controller function to count the unread log entries in the attached list of log entries.

This in the HTML:

```
<span class="badge">{{$ctrl.countUnread(system.logEntries)}} of {{system.logEntries.length}}</span>
```

And as part of my controller:

```
SystemView.prototype = {
  setRead: function () {
    // ...
  },

  countUnread: function (logEntries) {
    var unread = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < logEntries.length; i++) {
      if(logEntries[i].isUnread) { unread++; }
    }
    return unread;
  }
};
```

This worked for me. Maybe there is a better solution for that, but this solved my problem.